# Google Adwords multiple scripts in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

I need to put two (google adwords) scripts in same page. Is it safe to put two scripts at same page ?

```
<!-- Google Code for 2016-05 transaction tracking Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxx;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "asdsad"; 
var google_conversion_value = 0.00; 
var google_conversion_currency = "USD"; var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxxx/?value=0.00&currency_code=USD&label=sasdsaM&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

The other adowrds conversion script

```
<!-- Google Code for 2016-05 transaction tracking Conversion Page --> <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxx;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "3";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "dsadsa"; 
    var google_conversion_value = 5.00; 
    var google_conversion_currency = "USD"; var google_remarketing_only = false;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxxx/?value=5.00&currency_code=USD&label=sasdsaM&guid=ON&script=0"/>
    </div>
    </noscript>
```

I just want to know if both scripts run fine simentaniously ? Can there be any problem on loading one script twice and declearing google_conversion_xxx variables twice ?

If not safe then what is other way around for this ?

Comment: You can check if it is working with the Google Tag Assistant, if it is not working properly you can use one of the scrips in "noscript" mode

Comment: @fabrigm noscript only run if javascript is disabled in the browser. This is not aption for me.

Comment: That is true, but I'm talking about the img (pixel) inside the noscript tag, without the noscrip tag...

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Track multiple kinds of conversions

Do you want to track multiple kinds of conversions from the list above? Just set up a different conversion action for each type of conversion you want to track. For example, you can set up one conversion action to track purchases on your website, and another to track calls from your ads.

You can also set up multiple conversion actions for each conversion source. For example, say you want to track two different actions on your website: purchases and newsletter sign-ups. You’d set up two conversion actions: one for the purchases and one for sign-ups.

If you’re tracking multiple conversion actions, you might want to use the “Include in ‘Conversions’” setting to choose which conversions to include in your “Conversions” reporting column. Learn more